# Login into a Webpage using C# selenium that has an anti-forgery token

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, antiforgerytoken, csrf-token

I have two web-scrapes that i am trying to rewrite from access to c#. the access version uses html and vba but can log into the sites no problem. The c# versions using selenium cant get past the login in screen one site uses a CSRF token and the other uses an Antiforgerytoken. I have been using the send keys method to input the user data and then click on the submit button.

the site that uses the CSRF token - I have tried submitting the data by send keys and java but it always states that there is missing login data

the site with the Antiforgerytoken -  i have tried the same as above but with this one the form just reloads in on its self.